# Cannot convert System.Xml.XmlNode to System.Xml.Linq.XElement

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I´m getting the error Calling the function GetListItems but is kind weird because it works in Visual Studio 2008 Express but no in Visual Basic 2010 Express:

```
 Dim ndQuery As XmlNode = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "")

    Dim ndViewFields As XmlNode = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", "")
    Dim ndQueryOptions As XmlNode = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "QueryOptions", "")

    ndQueryOptions.InnerXml = "<IncludeMandatoryColumns>False</IncludeMandatoryColumns>" & _
                                "<DateInUtc>True</DateInUtc>"

    ndViewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name=""LinkFilename"" />" & _
                            "<FieldRef Name=""Empresa"" />" & _
                            "<FieldRef Name=""Puesto"" />" & _
                            "<FieldRef Name=""Fecha_x0020_Vigente"" />" & _
                            "<FieldRef Name=""Oferta_x0020_vigente"" />"

    ndQuery.InnerXml = ""

    Try

        Dim ndListItems As XmlNode = IntranetLists.GetListItems(ListUUID, Nothing, _
                                                    ndQuery, ndViewFields, Nothing, ndQueryOptions, Nothing)
```

And this is the function i´m calling:

```
Public Function GetListItems(ByVal listName As String, ByVal viewName As String, ByVal query As System.Xml.Linq.XElement, ByVal viewFields As System.Xml.Linq.XElement, ByVal rowLimit As String, ByVal queryOptions As System.Xml.Linq.XElement, ByVal webID As String) As System.Xml.Linq.XElement
        Dim inValue As ListasIntranetGureak.GetListItemsRequest = New ListasIntranetGureak.GetListItemsRequest()
        inValue.Body = New ListasIntranetGureak.GetListItemsRequestBody()
        inValue.Body.listName = listName
        inValue.Body.viewName = viewName
        inValue.Body.query = query
        inValue.Body.viewFields = viewFields
        inValue.Body.rowLimit = rowLimit
        inValue.Body.queryOptions = queryOptions
        inValue.Body.webID = webID
        Dim retVal As ListasIntranetGureak.GetListItemsResponse = CType(Me,ListasIntranetGureak.ListsSoap).GetListItems(inValue)
        Return retVal.Body.GetListItemsResult
    End Function
```

Comment: If it's not working, please tell us the *way* in which it's not working. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: What is the first section of code that you posted? It's obviously incomplete. There's no way I can reproduce the problem to see what error you're getting.

Comment: In the example you convert XElement to XmlNode; but the question asks XmlNode to XElement...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have VB 2008 handy, but to the best of my knowledge there has *never* been any automatic conversion (implicit or explicit) between `XElement` and `XmlNode` - LINQ-to-XML is largely a *parallel* implementation of a DOM, with only a few things (like `XmlReader` as a source) in common.

However; in terms of addressing the *issue*, the best I can suggest is to work with the xml; a C# example (using `CreateReader` to avoid having to go via a `string`):

```
XElement el = new XElement("foo",
     new XAttribute("abc","def"), new XElement("bar"));
var doc = new XmlDocument();
using (var reader = el.CreateReader()) {
    doc.Load(reader);
}
XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement; // node could also be typed as XmlElement
```

and to convert it back again (to match the question title):

```
XElement andBackAgain;
using(var reader = new XmlNodeReader(node)) {
    andBackAgain = XElement.Load(reader);
}
```